# Char to Decimal/Double in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion

Can anyone help me to for below coding, how to convert String to Decimal/Double.

I have received the following error when running these code.

"Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT"

```
(case when
(select max(IT.TRACE_QUANTITY) from BRDB.IMPORT_TRACE IT where IT.FILE_NO = IS.FILE_NO and IT.TRACE_TYPE = 'CO' and IT.TRACE_UNIT = '40H') is null
then ''
else decimal('1.125')
end) as "40H"
```

the reason i convert it is to sum all the numbers i need.
I want to convert '1.125' to double or decimal

Comment: Are you using Oracle?

Comment: @Aleksej yes Oracle

Comment: "Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT" does not seem to be an Oracle error

Answer (score 1):

Would `TO_NUMBER` (with appropriate format mask) help? For example:

```
SQL> select to_number('1.125', '99999D999', 'nls_numeric_characters = .,') result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
     1,125

SQL>
```

Comment: What is "not working"? It works, as you can see from example I posted. Could you edit your message and post your SQL*Plus session?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `1.125` directly instead of `else decimal('1.125')`:

```
(case when
(select max(IT.TRACE_QUANTITY) from BRDB.IMPORT_TRACE IT where IT.FILE_NO =  IS.FILE_NO and IT.TRACE_TYPE = 'CO' and IT.TRACE_UNIT = '40H') is null
then ''
else 1.125
end) as "40H"
```